# Cannot configure Neo4j and JUnit with annotations

Tags: junit, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I am converting the spring.io guide for [accessing Neo4j](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-neo4j/) to use JUnit.  However, it's not working out.  I receive the message:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hello.TestIt': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Can't work with a null graph database
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
....
```

I added two dependencies to the pom:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Here is the complete Unit test.  It is a copy of main() with the config changes I believe are necessary for JUnit:

```
package hello;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.GraphDatabase;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoader;


@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "hello")
@ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class TestIt extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    @Configuration
    static class ContextConfiguration {
        @Bean
        GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
            return new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("accessingdataneo4j.db");
        }
    }

    @Before
    public void init() {
        setBasePackage("hello");
    }

    @Autowired
    PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Autowired
    GraphDatabase graphDatabase;

    @Test
    public void t1() {
        Person greg = new Person("Greg");
        Person roy = new Person("Roy");
        Person craig = new Person("Craig");

        System.out.println("Before linking up with Neo4j...");
        for (Person person : new Person[]{greg, roy, craig}) {
            System.out.println(person);
        }

        Transaction tx = graphDatabase.beginTx();
        try {
            personRepository.save(greg);
            personRepository.save(roy);
            personRepository.save(craig);

            greg = personRepository.findByName(greg.name);
            greg.worksWith(roy);
            greg.worksWith(craig);
            personRepository.save(greg);

            roy = personRepository.findByName(roy.name);
            roy.worksWith(craig);
            // We already know that roy works with greg
            personRepository.save(roy);

            // We already know craig works with roy and greg

            System.out.println("Lookup each person by name...");
            for (String name: new String[]{greg.name, roy.name, craig.name}) {
                System.out.println(personRepository.findByName(name));
            }

            System.out.println("Looking up who works with Greg...");
            for (Person person : personRepository.findByTeammatesName("Greg")) {
                System.out.println(person.name + " works with Greg.");
            }

            tx.success();
        } finally {
            tx.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never seen a test itself used as configuration, try to move the config into a static inner class and declare that as dependency. I use that pattern a lot and it works.

I think otherwise the self-injection doesn't work.

Comment: I changed the config to static inner.  The code now runs.  However, it does not create a newEmbeddedDatabase - as the example that uses main().  Still puzzled.

Comment: you probably need `dirtiesContext=TEST_METHOD` on the Spring `@ContextConfiguration` annotation otherwise application contexts are cached